# Table sorting as per last column Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried all the solutions from other threads but nothing seems to work for me. I am trying to show the table with descending Weight Score (which is the last column of my table).

Here is the table for reference:

```
<table align="center" border="1px" cellpadding="5" id="caltbl" >

<thead>
<tr >
<th ><b>Slno</b></th>
<th><b>Mutual Fund Scheme</b></th>
<th><b>AUM</b></th>
<th><b>Last Year %</b></th>
<th><b>Two Years %</b></th>
<th><b>Three Years %</b></th>
<th><b>5 Years %</b></th>
<th><b>Weight Score</b></th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>UTI MNC Fund (G)</td>
<td>519</td>
<td>88</td>
<td>47</td>
<td>32</td>
<td>25</td>
<td class="sortnr">155.3</td>
</tr>
......
</tbody>

</table>
```

You can check the table [here](http://androidreskin.com/diversefund.php).

Please tell me how do I sort it as per Weight score column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/m0h9sz6r/

```
var $tbody = $('table tbody');
$tbody.find('tr').sort(function (a, b) {
    var tda = parseFloat($(a).find('td:eq(7)').text()); //the column to sort by
    var tdb = parseFloat($(b).find('td:eq(7)').text()); //the column to sort by
    // if a < b return 1
    return tda < tdb ? 1
    // else if a > b return -1
    :
    tda > tdb ? -1
    // else they are equal - return 0    
    :
    0;
}).appendTo($tbody);
```

Comment: Sorry but I am new to jsfiddle. Can you tell me if I need to add any library file as well. Because the above code though works in jsfiddle doesn't work in file I am working with. Also I created a html page with table and your script. Doesn't work as well. Please clarify if I need to add anything else.

Comment: You have to include the jquery library that's all. It looks like you for it you got it to work, right?

Comment: Yeah I added the library file and everything. It still doesn't work for me. Check link : androidreskin.com/diversefund.php
I have done what I did in new.html You can view its source: view-source:http://androidreskin.com/diversefund.php

Comment: I only hope PHP file is not the reason.

Comment: PHP should not be an issue. I see that you are using datatables now. is that what you want to go with"

Comment: Yeah seems so but your answer was helpful as well so I will vote up and pick your answer as right.